# Odd warning message when encrypting/decrypting

Tags: gedit, gnupg

I have imported my public and private keys and I can encrypt/decrypt.
However I always get this odd warning that requires a yes or no answer before completion:

> gpg: C8BB54DC: There is no assurance this key belongs to the named
>   user It is NOT certain that the key belongs to the person named in the
>   user ID.  If you *really* know what you are doing, you may answer the
>   next question with yes. Use this key anyway? (y/N)

What does it mean? And how can I suppress this message?

The reason I want to suppress it is that the gedit plugin fails when it receives this message.
The above problem is now resolved after adding ultimate trust to the keys. Thanks to jens erat.

Now for the decrypt:

In gedit Manage External Tools I set up a short script as per this image:

[image]
when I run it I get the message:

Running tool: Decrypt
gpg: cannot open tty `/dev/tty': No such device or address
Exited: 512

I was expecting to get asked for my passphrase

Answer (score 1):

This means that you did not verify the key ID `C8BB54DC`. If it is your own key, you should issue ultimate trust (run `gpg --edit-key C8BB54DC`, run `trust`, select ultimate).

If it is another person's key and you're sure about the key's ownership (for example compared at least the long key ID with what the key's owner provided to you), issue a signature with your own key (issue a local signature if you don't want it uploaded to the key server network) by running `gpg --edit-key C8BB54DC` as described above, but then using the `sign` or `lsign` commands.

Comment: with Ultimate Trust the encrypt worked -- thanks. Now I need to get the script for Decrypt working. I will edit my post to explain that problem too.